# Is there a way to get a line of text from a text widget if the line is set by a variable?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm making a new coding language in python for fun and I want to be able to get a certain line of text from a text box according to a variable that has the number of the line it should get the text from. How do I do this?

I haven't tried much only some basic code.

```
def shell_pressed_enter():
    code_line_run = shell.get(shell_line_number)
```

Comment: Your question is way too broad. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `shell` represents a `Text` widget, and `shell_line_number` is an integer representing the line number, you can use string formatting to create the starting and ending index:

```
start = "{}.0".format(shell_line_number)
end = "{}.0 lineend".format(shell_line_number)
code_line_run = shell.get(start, end)
```